# Security between rails and nodejs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, security, node.js

I have an app that is mostly in rails but also uses nodejs for some realtime features, for example, chat. Users log in via Rails and get assigned a session, etc as usual. However, what's the best way to authenticate with nodejs as that same user? For example I would like to prevent users from impersonating one another but login is done on rails right now and messaging is done on nodejs. Rails and nodejs both have access to the same database.

I am using devise and socketio if that matters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a number of ways implementation wise that you could tackle this. The one that jumps to mind is to share the session cookie that devise uses with nodejs via the database.

IIRC devise creates an encrypted session cookie during authentication; save this value temporarily to your database, and let nodejs pop it off the database for its authentication. There's likely some difficulty in accomplishing this (porting some of the devise encryption to nodejs, and the like) but if you're doing a rails/nodejs app, I'm pretty sure you're capable of handling it. :D

The benefit here is that a user can't get between the hand-off to accomplish impersonation.

Comment: Let me know if I am misunderstanding: So user hits rails and gets session (which is also stored in the db). User wants to chat so to connect it sends along the session which node can pop off the db to verify it's the same user. Something is sent back to the user for future nodejs communication?

Comment: Or can you add more details about the mechanics of how this will work?

Comment: @jhchen it depends whether the chat is run off of the same domain or not. If it's off the same domain or sub-domain, then the cookie will work across rails and nodejs, and the session in the db is for nodejs to identify it as a valid session. In the case that they're on different domains things get more complicated since you can't share a cookie across the domains; at which point you're implementing **Single Sign On** - I'm unfamiliar with implementation details for Single Sign On, but Google should be able to help there.

Comment: If you implement devise's encryption strategy in JS, there's no need to use a DB to transfer the session. Just read it from the client's request -- session cookies include a secure digest to prevent tampering. It might be easier to generate a one-time token for each user as they're passed from rails to node.

Answer (score 3):

You could always generate a one-time token for any user passed between rails and node. Much, much easier than re-implementing (and maintaining) the crypto strategy used by devise and rails.

That said, sharing sessions between servers creates a lot of extra work for you and effectively doubles your bug surface area (schema, validations, etc.)

Faye is an awesome project which handles this exact use case, so it's probably worth a look :) http://faye.jcoglan.com/

Comment: How exactly does Faye help if you want to have some API served by Rails and some by Node and share the session auth?

Comment: I'm also not understanding how Faye makes this scenario easier to manage. It seems to be Socket.io on Ruby steroids, but no integration with devise...

Comment: I think the point was to move the realtime stack to the current app. Unclear though.